# Поместить текст в переменную TelegramBot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, бот

в общем я делаю телеграм бота с помощью библиотеки *pyTelegramBotAPI*
И хочу сделать так чтобы пользователь писал какой нибудь текст, и этот текст помещался в перемеюу и потом в конце диалого выводил заявку типа
*Ваше имя: 'имя'*
Ваш возраст: 'возрась'*
Никак не могу понять как это сделать, хотя вроде нужно сделать "class" и туда поместите стандартные значения по типу
"self.name" итд...
Смотрела видео на Ютубе там в коду у одного парня была такая штуковина
user_data = {} и пыталась экспериментировать но нечего не вышло(

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если без ООП, то создается глобальная переменная и туда записывается все, только не забывайте ее очищать по мере необходимости.

```
user_data = {user_id:[message1,message2]}
```